# Annotation for Mandatory attribute in json validation in spring rest controller

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a spring rest service which accepts the Person object. Person object has a name, phone number, and email. While adding a person, the phone number is mandatory. If the phone number attribute is present, it validates for null or empties using `@NotNull` or `@NotBlank` or `@NotEmpty`. But if the attribute doesn't exist, the validation is not working. Please suggest any validation annotation present to check the attribute exists in JSON request.

following is the request body test cases

> {"name":"anu", "phoneNumber": "","email" :"test@gmail.com" } //
>   Validation works
>
> {"name":"anu", "phoneNumber": null,"email" :"test@gmail.com" } //
>   Validation works
>
> {"name":"anu","email" :"test@gmail.com" } // Validation doesnt works',
>   Required help to find the annotation.

```
class Person {
 @NotNull
private String name;
  @NotNull(message = "email.empty") 
   @Email(regexp = EMAIL_PATTERN, message = "email.invalid")
private String email;
 @NotNull(message = "phonenumber.empty")
   @Pattern(regexp = PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN, message = "phonenumber.invalid")
private String phoneNumber;
...
}
```

Please find my controler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createAdminPerson", method = POST, consumes = BusinessPersonConstants.MEDIA_TYPE, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> createAdminPerson(
            @Validated @RequestBody Person createAdminPerson) {
...
}
```

I tried @NotNull, @Notempty, @NotBlank. Please help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as its a basic validation for null attribute, Is there any bulit-in way to do so.

Comment: `@NotNull` workd perfectly fine for me. Is Person a inner object of some other object. Show the controller method signature

Comment: Please check the controller in the  edited question

Answer (score 0):

In controller, I have used @Validated to validate the request body, When I tried @Valid, the validation is working perfectly.!!